# acquiretokensilent msal angular 14 difference domains

Tags: acquiretokensilent

Silent Error: BrowserAuthError: monitor_window_timeout: Token acquisition in iframe failed due to timeout. For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.

const SsoSilentRequest = {
loginHint: 'Email' //Current Email Pass
}
this.authService.instance.ssoSilent(SsoSilentRequest).then((res) => {
if (res.idToken) { this.cookie.SetCookie('Token', res.idToken); }
}).catch(error => {
console.error("Silent Error: " + error);
});